# Restore data and structure from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Can I restore data and structure of a database in SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2012 instance directly?

Or is there any known limitations with this approach?

Comment: Backup & restore .....

Comment: And further can i open Sqlserver 2012 instance using my current installed SqlServer management Studio or Do i need a seperate one for it?

Comment: You should be able to manage SQL Server 2012 with your current Management Studio. You might not get access to all the new features in SQL Server 2012, though ....